# Несколько значений в один столбец

Tags: sql, mysql

Есть таблица отпусков. Каждый отпуск может быть связан с другим отпуском (например он был перенесен с другого отпуска). Вот структура:

```
vid  // id PK
start  // начало отпуска
originalVid // с какого отпуска был перенесен
```

Формирую таблицу по всем отпускам, и стала необходимость отобразить в ней куда (тут могут быть несколько записей) и откуда (тут все понятно) отпуск был перенесен.

**Как можно в один столбец записать все привязки по originalVid = vid ?**

К примеру есть табличка:

```
1   2013-10-10  (null)
2   2013-11-11  1
3   2013-11-22  1
4   2013-12-13  3
```

Нужно, что-то вроде:

```
1   2013-10-10      '2,3'
2   2013-11-11  1   
3   2013-11-22  1   '4'
4   2013-12-13  3
```

Вот структура на [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/46077/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *,(select group_concat(vid) from Vacation v2
          where V2.originalvid = V1.vid) FROM Vacation V1
```

Comment: спасибо :) Работает )